# Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined at DashboardComponent

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I keep getting the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined at DashboardComponent.push../src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts.DashboardComponent.getReferredUsers

My code is as follows:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ngxLoader.start();

    this.isMobile = this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.Handset]);
    this.campaignMode = environment.campaignMode;
    this.anonymousPhotoURL = 'https://i.imgflip.com/1slnr0.jpg';
    this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

    this.userService.getUserById(this.user.uid).subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        this.setUser(result);
        this.createReferralUrls();
        this.calculateNoOfUsers();
        this.calculateRanking();
        this.getReferredUsers();
        this.ngxLoader.stop();
      }
    });
  }
```

The error is happening here:

```
  getReferredUsers() {
    this.invitees$ = this.userService.getReferredUsers(this.userData.referralId).pipe(map(result => {
      return result;
    }));
  }
```

The method in ReferralService looks like this:

```
  getReferredUsers(referralId) {
    if (referralId) {
      return this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('referredBy', '==', referralId).limit(3)).valueChanges();
    }
  }
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getReferredUsers` returns undefined when `referralId` is `falsy`.

Debug what is the input of `getReferredUsers`. If it is 0, '', false, null, undefined, etc, and these are valid cases, then you should probably return some kind of empty observable so that caller doesn't fail with undefined.